# YII2 behavior attribute in response

Tags: response, yii2, behavior

I have a behavior defined in **components/testBehavior.php**:

```
class testBehavior extends Behavior
{
    protected $testField;

    public function getTestField()
    {
        return $this->testField;
    }

    public function setTestField($value)
    {
        $this->testField = $value;
    }
}
```

I need to extend model with additional **testField** property whose value relates on inner Id:

```
public static function getTestVehicles()
{
    $data = self::find()->all();
    foreach ($data as $k => $v) {
        $v->testField = $v->Id + 100;
    }

    return $data;
}
```

I need to output the extended data with a new property in JSON format:

```
public function actionJson()
{
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

    return Model::getTestVehicles();
}
```

But i see there is no **testField** property in output. How to add behavior extended property to response in FORMAT_JSON ?

Comment: Do you really need a behavior for this ? Did you properly add it to your model ?

Comment: Yes, cause when im using return $this->render('template', ['model' => $model]) the testField is in the template. So i need to form json from .html file. And thats not quite comfortable)

Answer (score 1):

My guess: the protected member `$testField` causes the problem. Make it public or use [JsonSerializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php) in your model class.